# How to set another start node besides the default one with FlowScoped?

Tags: jsf, cdi, jboss-weld, weld, flow-scope

An extract from Anghel Leonard's book,

> `<view tag>`: It is nested in the `<flow-definition>` tag and indicates the
>   JSF pages that represent the flow nodes; it associates an explicit ID
>   to each page (Facelet) path (further, you can refer to each page by
>   its ID). The page path is mapped in a `<vdl-document>` tag, nested in
>   the `<view>` tag. The presence of this tag is optional, but as a
>   convention, at least the `<view>` tag indicating the start node (start
>   page) is present, especially if you want to set another start node
>   besides the default one, which is represented by the page in the flow
>   with the same name (ID) as the flow. Further, you can use the optional
>   `<start-node>ID</start-node>` tag and indicate the ID of the `<view>` tag
>   that maps the custom starting page. As an alternative, the start node
>   of the flow can be indicated by setting the value of the id attribute
>   of a  tag as the flow ID, and the content of the encapsulated
>    tag as the path of the custom starting page. When you
>   refer to the flow ID, JSF will go to that page and automatically put
>   you in the flow.

Suppose I have 4 pages which are relative to `webapp` directory as shown:

```
index.xhtml
registration/registration.xhtml
registration/confirm.xhtml
done.xhtml
```

The author suggests this setting in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<flow-definition id="registration">
        <view id="registration">
            <vdl-document>/registration/registration.xhtml</vdl-document>
        </view>
        <flow-return id="taskFlowReturnIndex">
            <from-outcome>/index</from-outcome>
        </flow-return>
        <flow-return id="taskFlowReturnDone">
            <from-outcome>/done</from-outcome>
        </flow-return>
</flow-definition>
```

I have experiment it, and came to know that indeed,

```
<view id="registration">
    <vdl-document>/registration/registration.xhtml</vdl-document>
</view>
```

is optional as also put forward by the same author.

This is sufficient (the `id` attribute bearing the same name as of JSF view from where a flow needs to be created.)-

```
<flow-definition id="registration">
...
 </flow-definition
```

Furthermore, the flow will only be created if the `id` attribute for  `<flow-definition id="registration">` exactly matches the name of the JSF view, i.e:

`registration`.xhtml

Repeating a portion of the same extract:

> ...at least the `<view>` tag indicating the start node (start page) is
>   present, especially if you want to `set another start node` besides the
>   `default one`, which is represented by the page in the flow with the
>   `same name (ID)` as the flow. Further, you can use the optional
>   `<start-node>ID</start-node>` tag and indicate the `ID` of the `<view>` tag
>   that maps the custom starting page.

Put in much simpler words, he suggests like this to be done nested within the same `<flow-definition>`,

```
<view id="confirm">
     <vdl-document>/registration/confirm.xhtml</vdl-document>
</view>

<start-node>confirm</start-node>
```

But I see that going from `index.xhml` to `confirm.xhtml` doesn't return `true` for

```
In flow ? #{null != facesContext.application.flowHandler.currentFlow}
```

as for when one navigates from `index.xhtml` to `confirm.xhtml`.

Any suggestions?